# Find the shortest distance between the line $x + 2y = 1$ and the origin

Tags: geometry

The question is as stated, find the shortest distance between the line $x + 2y = 1$ and the origin in the coordinate system

Comment: Sounds like homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The shortest distance between a point and a line is the following:

$$\frac{|Ax_1+By_1+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

Where your linear formula is rearranged as $Ax+By+C$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ is the origin.

Can you continue?

Comment: I believe the answer is therefore 1/SQRT(5)

Comment: That's what I got too. Glad to see that given a start you did it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: the distance from a point to a line is the length of the perpendicular segment drawn from the point to the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just for illustrative purposes (using Mathematica):

1. Minimizing distance of point from point on given line:

   ```
   m[x_] := (1 - x)/2
   f[x_] := {x, m[x]}.{x, m[x]};
   p = {x, m[x]} /. Last@Minimize[f[x], x];
   vec = {1, -1/2};
   Sqrt[p.p]
   ```

   This yields $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$

I hope an instructive visualization:

[image]

2. As per Lanier Freeman:

   ```
   np[nm_, pt_, tg_] := Module[{u = Normalize@nm, d},
   d = u.(pt - tg);
   Column[{
   ContourPlot[nm.({x, y} - pt) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Axes -> True,
   Epilog -> {Red, Point[tg], Line[{tg, tg + d u}]}], 
   Row[{"distance:", Abs[d]}]}, Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All]]
   ```

For this particular line and illustrate:

[image]